Spring not creating beans after Spring boot upgrade to 3.x from 2.7
I recently upgraded to Spring boot 3.0.12 from 2.7. But after doing the migration my integration tests are not running properly as they are missing spring beans. I started debug logging and it is not creating any beans.
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {
            AbcContextProviderITConfiguration.class
    },
    webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    properties = {
        "abc.app.id=testApp",
        "abc.api.version.major=1",
        "abc.app.web.validate_responses=false"
    })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AbcContextProviderIT {

    @Autowired
    AbcContextProviderImpl subject;

    @Configuration
    public static class AbcContextProviderITConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public ScheduledExecutorService decoratedExecutor(ThreadPoolFactory factory) {
            return factory.newBuilder("test").buildScheduledExecutorService();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void sampleTest() {
      ...
    }
}

Error:
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.abc.impl.AbcContextProviderIT
10:24:23.877 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper -- Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [AbcContextProviderIT]: using SpringBootContextLoader
10:24:23.882 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader -- Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.abc.impl.AbcContextProviderIT]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
10:24:23.926 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper -- Using ContextCustomizers for test class [AbcContextProviderIT]: [ImportsContextCustomizer, ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer, DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer, MockitoContextCustomizer, TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer, DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer, PropertyMappingContextCustomizer, WebDriverContextCustomizer]
10:24:24.089 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper -- Using TestExecutionListeners for test class [AbcContextProviderIT]: [ServletTestExecutionListener, DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, MockitoTestExecutionListener, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, MicrometerObservationRegistryTestExecutionListener, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, TransactionalTestExecutionListener, SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, EventPublishingTestExecutionListener, ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, RestDocsTestExecutionListener, MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, WebDriverTestExecutionListener, MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener]
10:24:24.091 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener -- Before test class: class [AbcContextProviderIT], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null]
10:24:24.106 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener -- Performing dependency injection for test class com.abc.impl.AbcContextProviderIT
10:24:23,664 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - This is logback-classic version 1.4.11
10:24:23,666 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@6124287a - No custom configurators were discovered as a service.
10:24:23,666 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@6124287a - Trying to configure with ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator
10:24:23,667 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@6124287a - Constructed configurator of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator
10:24:23,692 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.scmo]
10:24:23,692 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.scmo]
10:24:23,702 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@6124287a - ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator.configure() call lasted 26 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY
10:24:23,702 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@6124287a - Trying to configure with ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator
10:24:23,702 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@6124287a - Constructed configurator of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator
10:24:23,703 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
10:24:23,704 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.xml]
10:24:23,704 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@6124287a - ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configure() call lasted 2 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY
10:24:23,704 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@6124287a - Trying to configure with ch.qos.logback.classic.BasicConfigurator
10:24:23,706 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@6124287a - Constructed configurator of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.BasicConfigurator
10:24:23,706 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.BasicConfigurator@19569ebd - Setting up default configuration.
10:24:23,736 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@6124287a - ch.qos.logback.classic.BasicConfigurator.configure() call lasted 30 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=NEUTRAL
10:24:24,458 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@4632cfc - URL [jar:file:/Users/xyz/.m2/repository/com/sconems/scone-starter-logging-json/9.2.4/scone-starter-logging-json-9.2.4.jar!/logback-spring.xml] is not of type file
10:24:24,532 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.IncludeAction - Could not find resource corresponding to [logback.custom.config_IS_UNDEFINED]
10:24:24,538 |-WARN in IfNestedWithinSecondPhaseElementSC - <if> elements cannot be nested within an <appender>, <logger> or <root> element
10:24:24,538 |-WARN in IfNestedWithinSecondPhaseElementSC - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#nested_if_element
10:24:24,545 |-WARN in IfNestedWithinSecondPhaseElementSC - Element <appender> at line 47 contains a nested <if> element at line 52
10:24:24,545 |-WARN in IfNestedWithinSecondPhaseElementSC - Element <appender> at line 89 contains a nested <if> element at line 90
10:24:24,545 |-WARN in IfNestedWithinSecondPhaseElementSC - Element <appender> at line 89 contains a nested <if> element at line 99
10:24:24,545 |-WARN in IfNestedWithinSecondPhaseElementSC - Element <appender> at line 89 contains a nested <if> element at line 116
10:24:24,836 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.conditional.IfModelHandler - Condition [property("isDevelopment").equals("false") && !property("logging.enabled").toLowerCase().equals("false")] evaluated to false on line 45
10:24:24,840 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.conditional.IfModelHandler - Condition [!property("file.enabled").toLowerCase().equals("false")] evaluated to false on line 87
10:24:24,841 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@6e1f8469 - End of configuration.
10:24:24,841 |-INFO in org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator@2e380628 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point


  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v3.0.13)


============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

    None


Negative matches:
-----------------

    None


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.334 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.abc.impl.AbcContextProviderIT
[ERROR] com.abc.impl.AbcContextProviderIT.testStackedContext  Time elapsed: 0.007 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@586cc15d testClass = com.abc.impl.AbcContextProviderIT, locations = [], classes = [com.abc.impl.AbcContextProviderIT.AbcContextProviderITConfiguration], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = ["classpath:test.properties"], propertySourceProperties = ["abc.app.id=testApp", "abc.api.version.major=1", "abc.app.web.validate_responses=false", "org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true", "server.port=0"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@6c835217 key = [@org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest(args={}, classes={com.abc.impl.AbcContextProviderIT.AbcContextProviderITConfiguration.class}, properties={"abc.app.id=testApp", "abc.api.version.major=1", "abc.app.web.validate_responses=false"}, useMainMethod=NEVER, value={"abc.app.id=testApp", "abc.api.version.major=1", "abc.app.web.validate_responses=false"}, webEnvironment=RANDOM_PORT), @org.apiguardian.api.API(consumers={"*"}, since="5.0", status=STABLE), @org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource(inheritLocations=true, inheritProperties=true, locations={"classpath:test.properties"}, properties={}, value={"classpath:test.properties"}), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class), @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration(excludeName={}, exclude={}), @org.springframework.context.annotation.Import({org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$Registrar.class}), @org.springframework.context.annotation.Import({org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.class}), @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackage(basePackages={}, basePackageClasses={})]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6e01f9b0, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@59d4cd39, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@7cb502c, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@2812b107, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@9d1476c8], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:97)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:50)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'contextScopes' defined in class path resource [com/abc/v2/platform/context/impl/ContextAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'contextScopes' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.inject.Provider<com.abc.AbcContextProvider>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:191)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:779)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:597)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1385)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:119)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.inject.Provider<com.abc.AbcContextProvider>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1824)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1383)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:910)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
    ... 98 more

I tried going through all the Spring migration documentation and enable debug logs to see why is it happening, but was not able to figure this out.

Your integration test uses AbcContextProviderITConfiguration.class to configure all the beans and AbcContextProviderImpl is not defined inside the configuration. I am not sure how that looked before the migration but adding @ComponentScan and indicate the package where AbcContextProviderImpl  exists should solve your issue I believe.

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = ConfigurableApplicationContext.class)
@Import(AbcContextProviderImpl.class)
public class AbcContextProviderIT {

@Autowired
AbcContextProviderImpl instance;

// other mock beans , as required by AbcContextProviderImpl

}

You should keep one application-test.properties file that has test properties and the required @Value based variables will be injected from there.
Take a look if it works for you !
